# Spring/Hibernate call Oracle pipelined function

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to call a package with a pipelined function from my Spring service.

I have:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery( "select * from table(MY_PACKAGE.MY_FUNCTION(var1))");
List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();
```

But whenever I execute `getResultList()` it i get the following SQL error:

> SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
>
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
>
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet

There is very little documentation and examples online for calling pipelined functions with JPA. 
The closes only good example I have seen is this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1029019

Does anyone have an idea of what is going wrong or know of a good example?

Comment: Looks like var1 is the invalid identifier. Perhaps you mean to pass a parameter to MY_FUNCTION and have the value bound from your calling program?

Comment: @jeff6times7 I actually found the issue. It was because the user credentials i was using in my `application.properties` file did not have permission to execute the package. After I did a `grant` everything worked as it should.